# How would you design database relationships based from the following data..?

Tags: mysql, django, database, sqlite, database-design

How would you frame the data in a relational database? When I update the database I would like to add a corresponding batch number (batch_no) to both tables so that data can be linked. How would I do this?

First table (that may need to split up????) are the classification results from the data upload.

```
+--------------+-----------+--------+----------+---------+----------+
|              | precision | recall | f1-score | support | batch_id |
+--------------+-----------+--------+----------+---------+----------+
|              |           |        |          |         |          |
| positive     | 0.56      | 0.7    | 0.62     |    1034 |        1 |
| negative     | 0.96      | 0.94   | 0.95     |    8966 |        1 |
|              |           |        |          |         |          |
| micro avg    | 0.91      | 0.91   | 0.91     |   10000 |        1 |
| macro avg    | 0.76      | 0.82   | 0.79     |   10000 |        1 |
| weighted avg | 0.92      | 0.91   | 0.92     |   10000 |        1 |
|              |           |        |          |         |          |
| positive     | 0.56      | 0.7    | 0.62     |    1034 |        2 |
| negative     | 0.96      | 0.94   | 0.95     |    8966 |        2 |
|              |           |        |          |         |          |
| micro avg    | 0.91      | 0.91   | 0.91     |   10000 |        2 |
| macro avg    | 0.76      | 0.82   | 0.79     |   10000 |        2 |
| weighted avg | 0.92      | 0.91   | 0.92     |   10000 |        2 |
+--------------+-----------+--------+----------+---------+----------+
```

Second table are the many reviews.

```
+----+------------+-----------+--------+----------+
| id | reviewtext | predicted | actual | batch_id |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+----------+
|  1 | blah blah  | pos       | neg    |        1 |
|  2 | blah blah  | pos       | pos    |        1 |
|  3 | blah blah  | neg       | neg    |        1 |
|  4 | blah blah  | pos       | neg    |        2 |
|  5 | blah blah  | pos       | pos    |        2 |
|  6 | blah blah  | neg       | neg    |        2 |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+----------+
```

I've tried experimenting with composite keys and splitting the first database to positive and negative then having a primary key which updates the reviews table but I can't seem clarify it in my head.

Answer (score 0):

Your "classification" table should have an "id" column as a primary key:

```
---+--------------+-----------+--------+----------+---------+
 id|              | precision | recall | f1-score | support | 
---+--------------+-----------+--------+----------+---------+
  1|              |           |        |          |         | 
  2| positive     | 0.56      | 0.7    | 0.62     |    1034 |
  3| negative     | 0.96      | 0.94   | 0.95     |    8966 |
  4|              |           |        |          |         |
  5| micro avg    | 0.91      | 0.91   | 0.91     |   10000 |
  6| macro avg    | 0.76      | 0.82   | 0.79     |   10000 |
  7| weighted avg | 0.92      | 0.91   | 0.92     |   10000 |
---+--------------+-----------+--------+----------+---------+
```

Then on your "reviews" table, create a foreign key to the "classification" table:

```
---+------------+-----------+--------+------------------+
 id| reviewtext | predicted | actual | classification_id|
---+------------+-----------+--------+------------------+
  1| blah blah  | pos       | neg    |        1         |
  2| blah blah  | pos       | pos    |        2         |
  3| blah blah  | neg       | neg    |        3         |
---+------------+-----------+--------+------------------+
```

Now, if you want to access the data from both tables in one query, you can `JOIN` the tables:

```
SELECT 
*.t1,
*.t2
FROM classification t1
LEFT JOIN reviews t2
ON (t1.id = t2.classification_id)
```

If you need help doing this with Django's ORM, update your post with your models and let me know.

Comment: One classification report (see table 1) corresponds to multiple entries in the review table. 
I need to identify which batch/upload the classification report and set of reviews corresponds to.